# laravel построение чпу маршрута для поиска с переменным количеством параметров

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация, search, чпу, slug

сделал такой маршрут

```
Route::get('/search/{query?}', 'SearchController@test')->name('search');
```

хочу чтобы все параметры после **search/** принимались в переменную **query** и затем я парсил поисковый запрос. данная задача возникла потому что необходимо отфильтровать сразу по нескольким параметрам. форма поиска к примеру состоит из 6ти параметров (город, район, метро, параметр1, параметр2) и они могут быть выбраны в любой комбинации. все эти параметры являются слагами.

и могут быть ссылки типа

```
my.site/search/city-msk/metro-arbatskaya

my.site/search/metro-arbatskaya

my.site/search/metro-arbatskaya/param1-slug

my.site/search/city-msk/param1-slug
```

и это не полный список того какими они могут быть. и фишка в том что не получится построить такой маршрут

```
Route::get('/search/{city?}/{metro?}/{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}', 'SearchController@test')->name('search');
```

потому что  параметры могут быть в любом наборе.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощение. Сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос
[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes)

```
Route::get('search/{query?}', function ($search) {
    return $search;
})->where('query', '.*');
```